# How to make a horizontal navigation bar?

Tags: html, css, django

I am trying to make a website with a horizontal navigation bar. I found a useful reference, but I couldn't figure it out to be adopted to my current code since I am not an expert with HTML and CSS.

I like to create similar bar like this:

```
  ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
  }

  li {
    float: left;
  }

  li a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 14px 16px;
    text-decoration: none;
  }

  /* Change the link color to #111 (black) on hover */
  li a:hover {
    background-color: #111;
  }
```

And below are my current code:

```
{% block sidebar %}
    <ul class="sidebar-nav">
        <li><a href="{% url 'index' %">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="">All users</a></li>
        <li><a href="">All productss</a></li>
        <!-- <li><a href="">All vendors</a></li> -->
    </ul>
{% endblock %}
```

```
.sidebar-nav {
    margin-top: 20px;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
}
```

================================================================

#### Thank you for your help, but none of below three answers worked.

Here I add more of my .css code. I am guessing "col-sm-2" ruled my current code, but don't know how to adjust it to make a horizontal navigation bar.

```
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-2">
      {% block sidebar %}
        <ul class="sidebar-nav">
          <li><a href="{% url 'index' %">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="">All users</a></li>
          <li><a href="">All productss</a></li>
          <!-- <li><a href="">All vendors</a></li> -->
        </ul>
     {% endblock %}
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-10 ">{% block content %}{% endblock %}</div>
    </div>
'''
```

Answer (score 1):

The trick to get the list elements stack horizontally is to use the attribute float:left on the list items. Try adding something like this in your css-code

```
.sidebar-nav li {
    float:left;
}
```

By writing *.sidebar-nav li* you apply the style to all list-items (li) that is a child of sidebar-nav.

Answer (score 1):

## Update:

Now that we know you're using bootstrap, you can make a horizontal navbar just by adding a few classes:

The following code gives you a navbar with beautiful padding and margins:
Bootstrap navbar reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/components/navs/

```
<div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
          <!--'col-sm-12' to 'col-12' for 100% width -->
          {% block sidebar %}
          <ul class="sidebar-nav nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="{% url 'index' %">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">All users</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="">All productss</a>
            </li>
            <!-- <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="">All vendors</a></li> -->
          </ul>
          {% endblock %}
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-10 ">{% block content %}{% endblock %}</div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

#### The previous 'non-bootstrap' answer:

The goal is to align the "li" items horizontally so a simple and easy way is :

```
.sidebar-nav li{
  display: inline;
}
```

Display property reference:
https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I Assume you are using the bootstrap grid system. 
The class `col-sm-2` means your div will occupy 1/6th or 16.66% of the total container width on devices having screen width greater than 767px.
If you want your menu items to occupy the entire screen width, replace `col-sm-2` with `col-sm-12`.

My preferred way to do this is using `flex`.

```css
.sidebar-nav {
  display: flex;
}
```

This will ensure all elements inside the `ul` are displayed in a single line and they all have the same height which is equal to the height of the `ul`. Hope this helps.

Comment: This also helps you to avoid using floats which have a number of side effects and can be very confusing if you aren't well versed with CSS.

Comment: This link might be helpful for learning more about the bootstrap grid system:
https://mdbootstrap.com/docs/jquery/layout/grid-examples/